# Vim not sending correct xterm esc sequences back over an ssh connection to an OSX xterm

Tags: ssh, xterm

Running an xterm on MacOSX and connecting to an Ubuntu server using ssh, and using Vim to edit files on the Ubuntu server.

It is as if the 'clear to end of line' and 'clear up to first character' escape codes are not working. Moving up and down the file with <kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> are fine. Moving up and down between balanced '{}' pairs leaves the display with a mix of before and after screens. <kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> does not refresh the screen (assuming its still supposed to).

The inbuilt help is also unreadable due to the same problem. Using the `:` ex command often leaves characters at the bottom of the screen.

My `.vimrc` has:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set noshowmode
set autoindent
syntax off
```

and it is hard linked to `.virc` (I have been using `vi` since 1983)

Any ideas please?

Comment: What is the value of the `TERM` environment variable? It should be the same on both systems. `TERM` is used to determine which ESCape sequences are sent.

Comment: It's xterm on both systems. ssh tells the remote system what to use, but I have checked that they are the same.